# What is main difference between yarn and npm?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I want to ask what is your favorite package manager for JS ?
I saw some articles about yarn and npm. But I am not sure what can be better for me. I just start learning JS.

Right now difference between yarn and npm is for me like difference between brands of cola.

Comment: I saw some articles... but date of the articles was rlly different.. So thats why I asked here for actual info of yarn and npm users

Answer (score 73, accepted):

There were times when we had only `npm` but it had so many issues with resolving dependencies and caching that another tool has born (`yarn`). Usually it was using local cache to resolve dependencies and it was crucial for example while running CI jobs which are almost always ran in same environment and high bandwidth is costly as you pay for data in cloud services. That means in old `npm` versions when you ran `npm install` and you had lets in deps

## First note

Please understand that `yarn` was built on the top of `npm` packages and https://www.npmjs.com/ that means they are both using `NPM` registry for resolving packages. so if you run `npm install lodash@1.0.0.` or `yarn add lodash@1.0.0.` you will get very same result

## Incremental install

```
react@16.0.0
```

On every new build both dependencies were again downloaded from internet. Yarn uses `yarn.lock` underneath and it is comparing your `package.json` file with `yarn.lock` and determines which packages needs to be fetched additionally to only incrementally install new dependencies

## Multithreading

`yarn` offers parallel installation of packages which are not dependent in threads. It can lower installation time to 1/10 of time from `npm install`

## Version locking

As said before `yarn` generates `yarn.lock` after each installation which persists ALL versions of installed packages (as you probably know a package can have dependencies and a dependency can also have its own dependencies) so it can build up infinite tree of dependencies which can lead to very bad conflicts. Let's imagine this scenario

```
 - lodash^1
 - super_module@0.0.1
 - - lodash@1.0.0
 - another_module@0.0.01
 - - lodash@1.x.x
```

Imagine scenario when maintainer of `another_module` decides to bump lodash to breaking changes version `1.2.0` what can happen is that `npm` in old days could fetch 2 different instances of same library, and 2 different version which could lead to extremely weird behavior. Because as you don't have exact lock in your module (you accept any semver version ^1.x.x and ^2.x.x so that means both sub modules would satisfy your requirements but fetch different version. Yarn will lock your `yarn.lock` AT THE TIME OF AN ADDING new package to the project, that means when other developers on your project will checkout the project he will also have same `yarn.lock` and `yarn` will ultimately "mimic" the state of package how they were installed when you committed `yarn.lock` on other hands `NPM` just looks to the semver satisfaction and can fetch 2 different version for 2 developers (assuming that in time packages are upgrading)

## Final note

There has been a lot of work from `npm` guys as they released `npm@5` and I think all statements are now just reasons WHY `yarn` was created and which problems it was solving at the time, but I think at current date, it is no big difference between those 2 nowadays

Comment: I answered similar question elsewhere a few days ago, just a coincidence, didn't copy that from nowhere :)

Comment: @epascarello yeah yeah that how it goes .... it doesn't mean that when someone has 140k reputation others has to create an account for +15 reputation .... you can compare ISP's of accounts or review my profile ... if my answers are not legit .... that's damn ridiculous. Please re-read again this https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/ and reconsider again what you've asked just now in that comment. Thank you

Comment: I was thinking that stackoverflow is not so hostile environment but still thank you for answer :D Final note help me pretty much

Comment: npm :  The package manager for JavaScript. npm is the command-line interface to the npm ecosystem. It is battle-tested, surprisingly flexible, and used by hundreds of thousands of JavaScript developers every day.                                                                                                                   
 Yarn:  A new package manager for JavaScript. Yarn caches every package it downloads so it never needs to again. It also parallelizes operations to maximize resource utilization so install times are faster than ever.

Comment: I wonder where Webpack fits in, with Yarn and NPM...