# Understanding NPM vulnerability - tunnel-agent

Tags: npm

So I have a vulnerability in a package named `tunnel-agent`. After running `npm audit` the packages which depend on this package are listed:

- gatsby-plugin-sharp

OK great, I update this and everything is fine? NO.. Still listing as vulnerable, so now I start on the rabbit hole of looking where this leads.

Running `npm list tunnel-agent` I get to find out who's depending on this package.

[image: tunnel-agent]

So now the vulnerability is fixed in `tunnel-agent@0.6.0`but I've got one thing saying it's using `tunnel-agent@0.4.3`. But this is in the same package `gatsby-plugin-sharp` so why's it not fixed?

I head off to github issues and find that because `gatsby-plugin-sharp` uses `imagemin-mozjpeg` > `caw@1.2.0` > `tunnel-agent@0.4.3` I'm still stuck right?

So what I'm asking is, without relying on plugin authors to update their dependencies, how would you go about using `caw@2.0.1` which then uses `tunnel-agent@0.6.0` to remove this vulnerability once and for all?

Answer (score 1):

This is all environment variables.
But you could fork the open pull request that have not been merged published. Then create your on npm packages that have the fixes. 
 https://github.com/request/tunnel-agent/pull/45
 yarn negates these errors.

And ‘yarn’ doesn’t have these issue. Since it is designed for local scope.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the part about yarn not having these issues. Could you be more explicit about how yarn would help me over npm?

Comment: Sorry for the delay https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50278553/what-is-main-difference-between-yarn-and-npm