# Why one package's dependency impact another

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a folder which name is `project`.

I use "`yarn add`" to install two packages (`antd` and `antd-mobile`)，both of them have a dependency which name is `rc-checkbox`.

`antd` uses `"rc-checkbox": "~2.1.5"`.

`antd-mobile` uses `"rc-checkbox": "~2.0.0"`.

After running the command, `project/node_modules` has a 2.0.0 version `rc-checkbox` folder, and `project/node_modules/antd/node_modules` has a 2.1.5 `rc-checkbox` folder.

The weird thing is no matter which one I install first, `antd-mobile`'s 2.0.0 `rc-checkbox` will be installed at `project/node_module`. And when I run the project, `antd` uses the `rc-checkbox` which version is 2.0.0 (it is supposed to use 2.1.5) and it causes the bug.

So why would this happen? I think two packages use same another package with difference version should not impact each other.

Answer (score 0):

Copy from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50278575/4925026)

## Version locking

`yarn` generates `yarn.lock` after each installation which persists ALL versions of installed packages (as you probably know package can has also dependencies and dependency can have also dependency) so it can build up infinite tree of dependencies which can lead to very bad conflicts. Let's imagine this scenario

```
 - lodash^1
 - super_module@0.0.1
 - - lodash@1.0.0
 - another_module@0.0.01
 - - lodash@1.x.x
```

Imagine scenario when maintainer of `another_module` decides to bump lodash to breaking changes version `1.2.0` what can happen is that `npm` in old days could fetch 2 different instances of same library, and 2 different version which could lead to extremely weird behavior. Because as you don't have exact lock in your module (you accept any semver version ^1.x.x and ^2.x.x so that means both sub modules would satisfie your requirements but fetch different version. Yarn will lock your `yarn.lock` AT THE TIME OF AN ADDING new package to the project, that means when other developers on your project will checkout the project he will also have same `yarn.lock` and `yarn` will ultimately "mimic" the state of package how they were installed when you committed `yarn.lock` on other hands `NPM` just looks to the semver satisfaction and can fetch 2 different version for 2 developers (assuming that in time packages are upgrading)