# Difference between npm and yarn

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

Can you explain me what is the difference between:

- npm install -g
- yarn global add

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: basically u should use npm instead of yarn, for now.

Comment: @datdinhquoc ok but what is the difference ?

Comment: no diff, but we all need bigger community

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is main difference between yarn and npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50278553/what-is-main-difference-between-yarn-and-npm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yarn is, like NPM, a package manager for Node.JS.
Yarn is built by Facebook.
It's faster and has more features than NPM.
Their main selling points are:

Security
With yarn.lock file (similar to NPM's npm-shrinkwrap.json) all dependencies are locked on the exact version.
So, you don't have that “But it works on my machine” struggles anymore. Everyone has the same versions locked in yarn.lock file
Speed
Yarn uses (fast) proxies and (offline) caching to deliver your modules faster.
It also has a LICENSE checker, which checks the license of all your dependency modules.

However, Yarn is still in it's early days and under development.

Comment: Ok I see but do you know the install location for these two commands ?

Comment: can i install a package on npmjs.com using yarn? seems possible but yarn is scooping packages from npm registry

Comment: Kashmiri nice explanation,   @jeremy there is a good blog by Justin Dumadag on Medium you can also check it out here https://medium.com/@j.dumadag718/yarn-vs-npm-b2d58289fb9b